# Javascript/Jquery - Addition and Subtraction error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script to get the height of the browser, then the height of header and footer then subtract from the height of the browser:

```
var a = $(window).height();
alert (a);
var b = $('#header').css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
alert (b);
var c = $('#header').css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
alert (c);
var d = (a-(b+c));
alert (d);
$('#block').height(d);
```

SO it alerts,

1.)699

2.)100

3.)50

then the wrong part:

4.)-9351

What part is wrong here?

Comment: use this var d = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b) + parseInt(c));

Comment: yep, #4 is incorrect. output should be: (699-(100+50))= **549**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vars b and c contain Strings, when you use the + operator on Strings in Javascript they are concatenated.

i.e. the expression "100" + "50" evaluates to "10050".

I suggest getting the height of the elements with the jQuery `.height()` method

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt :

```
var a = parseInt($(window).height());
alert (a);
var b = parseInt($('#header').css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));
alert (b);
var c = parseInt($('#header').css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));
alert (c);
var d = (a-(b+c));
alert (d);
$('#block').height(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery height( returns integer) method.in your code b and c are string. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YX5zb/1/)

```
 var a = $(window).height();
    alert (a);
    var b = $('#header').height();
    alert (b);
    var c = $('#header').height();
    alert (c);
    var d = (a-(b+c));
    alert (d);
    $('#block').height(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...just replace the fixed numbers

```
var a = parseInt('600');
var b = parseInt('100');
var c = parseInt('50');
var d = (a-(b+c));
```